# When i convert reactjs web application to mobile app using capacitorjs I am getting error in android studio

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, okta-api

In my project I have used reactjs program with okta verification. when i run reactjs program, the output is getting good.

But when I convert reactjs webpage into mobile app using capacitorjs, the webpage is not displaying in mobile

I have followed steps in the below url for converting webpage to mobile app

https://medium.com/how-to-react/convert-your-existing-react-js-app-to-android-or-ios-app-using-the-ionic-capacitor-a127deda75bd

I am getting error in android studio after converting to mobile app

Error:

> E/Capacitor/Console: File: https://dev-26880336.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?client_id=0oa1mwa34crTomUOH5d7&code_challenge=kr1g6uGbNpAhaS56yKif3uwyoYFUhS4I7tq2A2hCxIo&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=SNKlf04bxtnRnB7QfSzXBkRe1wvOWJcUA5nq2B10hjpeaE8hk2vlFovVoRS0BM5z&prompt=none&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flogin%2Fcallback&response_mode=okta_post_message&response_type=code&sessionToken=20111eK94THVVdQCsGkgOQ4zWwQ1fH3xSkobMIPbeV3CnzPny2X_vlb&state=LOfoTu1kDHsTKrTFYvO4WaTfp76ie0ZraXp8qzCLPE5WAp4IHR7gnd86c16J8h5Y&scope=openid%20profile%20email - Line 42 - Msg: error.errorCode: invalid_request, error.description: The 'redirect_uri' parameter must be a Login redirect URI in the client app settings: https://dev-26880336-admin.okta.com/admin/app/oidc_client/instance/0oa1mwa34crTomUOH5d7#tab-general

In Okta Developer console I have added following credentials

[image: Click here to view Okta credentials]

I have added trusted origin in Okta developer console as below

[image: Click here to view trusted origin]

I am getting error in android studio and web page is not opening in mobile app.

I am getting output as below

[image: Click here to view output]

I did not where it is going error. Either in Okta or in AndroidStudio

Answer (score 0):

Your callback URL parameters requested does not match your configured login redirect URI

Comment: But my webpage is working only mobile app is not working